# How to Add Array In Dictionary Based Key Name In Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying To add Array In My Dictionary.

[image]

How to add **Details2** In **ProductDetails** of **Details1** So I can Display On TableView Which Each row is Containing Collection View.

```
(((((self.completeDetailsArray[index] as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy()) as! NSMutableDictionary).value(forKey: "productDetails") as! NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray).addObjects( from: productArray )
```

***I tried This One Which is not working***

```
let productArray : NSArray = responseResult.value(forKey: "details2") as! NSArray

            let oldProductDict : NSMutableDictionary = (self.completeDetailsArray[index] as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
            let oldProductArray : NSArray = oldProductDict.value(forKey: "productDetails") as! NSArray

            let completeProductArray = oldProductArray.addingObjects(from: productArray as! [Any])
            oldProductDict.setValue(completeProductArray, forKey: "productDetails")

            self.completeDetailsArray.replaceObject(at: index, with: oldProductDict)

            let oldProductDict2 : NSDictionary = self.completeDetailsArray[index] as! NSDictionary
            print("oldProductDict2",oldProductDict2)
```

***This is Working Is This Correct Solution Or I can Use Any Other Way***

Comment: First of all, don't make such long and complex statement. Break it down into multiple statements.

Comment: @Moritz I added New Code Which is working fine. So I am Asking is any other way of this best solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can get each element of details1 like

```
var new = details1[0]
```

and now add

```
new["productDetails"] = details2
```

and add new into main array like

```
details[0] = new
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to convert JSON to model class or struct using [JSONExport](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport)

then you can make this like that

```
let details2:[ProductDetails] = [ProductDetails]()
details1.productDetails = details2
```